# Can opennebula act as ec2 server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, condor, opennebula

My question is, can opennebula act as ec2 server, so that I can connect HTCondor with it.
I am planning to connect HTCondor with OpenNebula cloud. Some one told me that Opennebula can act as ec2 server, is it possible?
If yes, please let me know how to achieve this, or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It can.

You may want to check the following guide on how to configure and use the EC2 server on top of OpenNebula:

- Configuration: http://docs.opennebula.org/4.14/advanced_administration/public_cloud/ec2qcg.html
- User guide:
  http://docs.opennebula.org/4.14/advanced_administration/public_cloud/ec2qug.html